# Well order proof that a² -a is divisible by 2 if a is a natural number

Tags: proof-explanation, well-orders

I want to prove that a² -a is divisible by 2 for all a that is natural. Here is what I know:

1. If a is even a² is even, if a is odd a² is odd.
2. a² − a is a substraction if and only if a is natural.
3. Any even number substracted by an even number is even. Any odd number substracted by an odd number is even.
4. Since a²-a is always even and even numbers are divisible by 2, a²-a is divisible by 2.

Not the most elegant proof but I think it works. How do I prove this by well order principle?

Comment: Simplify the expression as $a(a-1)$. Now you can see that if a is even then (a-1) will be odd and vice versa....hence the given expression always has an even factor and is therefore divisible by 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well-ordering principle: any non-empty set of natural numbers has a smallest element.

Natural numbers: I shall assume you mean $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ but if you mean $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ then you will find it is easy to modify the proof.

Let $S$ be the set of natural numbers $a$ for which $a^2-a$ is **not** even.  Suppose that $S$ is not empty.  Then $S$ has a smallest element, call it $b$.  Now $b\ne0$ since $0^2-0$ is even.  So $b-1$ is a natural number.  Also,
$$(b-1)^2-(b-1)=(b^2-b)-2b+2\ ,$$
and this is odd because $b^2-b$ is odd and the other terms are even.  Therefore $b-1$ is in $S$.  But this is impossible because $b$ was the smallest element of $S$.

Our assumption that $S$ is not empty has led to a contradiction and is therefore false: that is, $S$ is the empty set.  Hence $a^2-a$ can never be odd and is always even.  This completes the proof.